# Magento returning incorrect customer data on frontend pages

Tags: magento

isn't this the right method to get Name of logged in customer?

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getName(); ?>
```

I have a website with live chat functionality. Yesterday I have been asked to pass email address and the name of the logged into the user into the Javascript Tracking variable code placed in the head section of the website. So that the operators could see who is on the website and whom are they talking to without any need to ask about their information.

So I passed the information from Magento into the Javascript code but now I see this very **strange thing** happening. For example,

> If I am logged in with credentials  Name = John Email =
>   john12@yahoo.com

Then This name and email variable values are changing with the change of pages. For example if I click on any product page the variable values which I am passing changes to some other user's information.

> Name becomes Ricky Email becomes ricky23@gmail.com

this variable values are kept on changing back to john and from john to something else with the change of pages. So operator does not have any idea whom are they talking because the values are kept on changing. Also, user ricky or who ever it changes to also exist in the database. so it is picking up random person from the database.

This is what i did to pass the code to javascript. Please let me know if that is not the right code to pass the information. Please check the php code I am using to fetch information from Magento. Roughly, I receive  incorrect value once in 5 times. Please provide some assistance. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail();
$firstname = $customer->getFirstname();
$lastname= $customer->getLastname();
$name = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (typeof(lpMTagConfig) == "undefined"){ lpMTagConfig = {};}
      if (typeof(lpMTagConfig.visitorVar) == "undefined"){ lpMTagConfig.visitorVar = [];}
      lpMTagConfig.visitorVar[lpMTagConfig.visitorVar.length] = 'Email=<?php echo $email; ?>';
      lpMTagConfig.visitorVar[lpMTagConfig.visitorVar.length] = 'Name=<?php echo $name; ?>';

    </script>
```

I'm also attaching a snap shot
[image: I am logged in as Gagan Sharma but in Google developer tool you can see it's showing me some other guy from the database Warwick Burton]

Comment: I doubt the issue is with getcustomer,how are you saving the information passed to the javascript, then displaying that information to operator?  what I think is happening that the information is overwritten everytime a customer visits the site. that's why it seems showing by random.  can you show relevant code from your tracker?

Comment: That's the only code they have provided. javascript code in my question and passing php variables to it.

Comment: Did you try to use session scope in your live chat admin instead of visitor scope?  and paste the new code in footer.phtml with ALL caches disabled in magento and sees if it works?

Comment: yes i hv tried session, vistior any page variables aswell

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have sorted this out. I have moved the code from footer.phtml to head.phtml and it's working fine now.Values are not changing anymore. If anyone know the logic behind please post and I will change my answer. So far this is working.

Comment: I think so far moving the code from footer to header is a working solution to this issue. At this stage I really needed this functionality to be done rather than jumping into logic behind. But if you think you have the solution for it, why don't you add another answer and if it will be working. Me and everyone will be more than happy for it and I will change my answer. So far If anyone needed this is the right thing to try and get the stuff done on time.

Comment: The issue you were facing, was beacause in Magento footer.phtml output is cached for language, customer group and store code. For head block the data is not cached. Occasionally cache is recorded by different persons who is logged in and another user receives this cached data until the cache is revalidated and flushed again.

Comment: It depends on what kind of cache you disabled. Sometimes Magento caches data without taking care about disabled cache types.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested to hear how you're adding this code to the page?  Is it in it's own block, or are you adding it to `footer.phtml`, or similar?  If your adding to an existing block be sure to check the block caching settings of that template.

To confirm the caching hypothesis I'd ask the following:

- Do you get the same name, all the time, on the same page?  When you refresh the page, do you get the same name and email in the Javascript?
- Does the problem persist with caching disabled?

This doesn't sound like a singleton problem at all.  Each execution of the PHP script is isolated from the others, serving one page request.  There's no chance of another customer's object moving between invokations of the script.

Comment: I am putting the javascript code to footer.phtml.That's where they are suggesting before the end of the body. After successful login the values just change between 2 users only, the one obviously the original user and other could be anyone, but I have seen other user is also logged in from somewhere else. So values switch between those two only. If I log out and log in again then other user could be anyone but it has to be logged in aswell.

Comment: Yes problem still exist with cache disabled.

Comment: The footer actually has some url based caching going on, try putting it in another file.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of understanding the singleton pattern. If you call your code twice:

```
$customer_1 = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getName(); 
$customer_2 = Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getName();
```

you get **two different** instances of the object. But... if one of them has already implemented a singleton pattern in its constructor or has implemented a singleton `getInstance` then both objects will actually point to the same thing.
Looking at the `customer/helper/Data.php` code you can see the function

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    if (empty($this->_customer)) {
        $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    }
    return $this->_customer;
}
```

That means that in one of the cases singleton is already implemented/called and in other one - not as the property is already set.
The correct way to work with quote/customer/cart in order to get always the correct data is always to use the singleton pattern.
So using this:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

always guarantee that you get the correct customer in that session. And as may be you know `singleton` pattern is based on `registry` pattern in `app/Mage.php`:

```
public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

and looking at `app/Mage.php`:

```
public static function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
{
    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        if ($graceful) {
            return;
        }
        self::throwException('Mage registry key "'.$key.'" already exists');
    }
    self::$_registry[$key] = $value;
}
...
public static function registry($key)
{
    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        return self::$_registry[$key];
    }
    return null;
}
```

you can see that Magento checks is it is already set. If so, Magento will either throw an Exception, which is the default behavior or return `null`. 
Hope this will help you to understand the issue you face.

Comment: Milen I have tried this aswell. But it still has not solved my problem. I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: The objects are session backed, so regardless of how many instances you create, you'll always be referencing the same data store and therefore the same data.  In any case, your suggestion is only avoiding the helper, then making the exact same code call which will obviously, as confirmed by the OP, lead to the same results..

Comment: Nick, just point of interest what you exactly mean by objects are session backed?